# Excel Formula to convert dates into Quarters

Tags: google-sheets

Tried to make a formula which catches the date and convert it into Q2-2021 as mentioned below.

I have tried and make formula but it is not working as i have required.

please see a attached sheet.

```
03-30-2021  =   Q2-2021
06-30-2021  =   Q3-2021
09-30-2021  =   Q4-2021
12-31-2021  =   Q1-2022
03-30-2022  =   Q2-2022
06-30-2022  =   Q3-2022
09-30-2022  =   Q4-2022
12-31-2022  =   Q1-2023
03-30-2023  =   Q2-2023
06-30-2023  =   Q3-2023
09-30-2023  =   Q4-2023
12-31-2023  =   Q1-2024
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FgVLXCoX4biaiVrbuL9V9RXdePQczWzgdKeDWOGxCNw/edit#gid=1831612213

Comment: So 3-30-2121 is the **first day** of Q2-2021 ??

Comment: Yes very strange, it isn't even the last day of March.

Comment: Gary's Student Yes for now it is first but it can be change.

Comment: Tom Sharpe, Yes these will be always last days, March, June, September and December

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("Q"&QUERY(B3:B14+1, 
 "select quarter(Col1) 
  label  quarter(Col1)''")&"-"&YEAR(B3:B14+1))
```

[image]

Comment: player0 Thank you so much

Comment: player0, There is one issue that is March end will be consider as Q2 and June end will be consider as Q3, September will be consider as Q4 and December will be Q1. Please re-verify it once.

Comment: thats how it is, or is it?

Comment: Instead of using ```+1``` use ```+2``` to solve this issue. Like this ```=ARRAYFORMULA("Q"&QUERY(B3:B14+2, 
 "select quarter(Col1) 
  label  quarter(Col1)''")&"-"&YEAR(B3:B14+1))```. Also as a brief explanation this formula uses mainly [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) which can select and add labels of different quarters. The main issue of the OP is that he wants to consider these specific days that are the limit between the previous and the next quarter as part of the next quarter rather than to the previous quarter (which they are usually set).

Comment: This formula also uses [YEAR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093061?hl=en) which returns the year. In the formula to satisfy OP's conditions some days are added to make this switch happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think this formula works properly:

=ifs(MONTH(B3)<4,"Q1",MONTH(B3)<7,"Q2",MONTH(B3)<10,"Q3",MONTH(B3)<13,"Q4") & "-" & YEAR(B3)

Comment: Martin Leisch, its not updating the next year on date 12-31-anyyear